# Get major versions NPM Package

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, npm

I am trying to get a list of all major version released of any particular **NPM package**.

I can find the versions including the **major** and the **experimental** version list by using the following API
[https://registry.npmjs.org/<pkg_name>](https://registry.npmjs.org/%3Cpkg_name%3E)

But can not distinguish from the **major** versions from the **experimental** or **non major** versions of the package. I am wondering how can I do that.

I have tried using a regex but it doesnt help.

**Here is my code**

```
const data = axios.get(`https://registry.npmjs.org/${packageName}`)

const regex = /(\d*)+[.]+(\d*)+[.]+(\d*)/g;
let versions: {}[] = [];

Object.keys(response.data).forEach((data: any) => {
    if (data.match(regex)) {
        versions.push(versionData);
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by major? Presumably `x.0.0`, without any `-alpha` or whatever, which seems easy enough to identify. What have you tried? Any specific problems with your implementation?

Comment: I am trying to get it in program. I get all version like `x.0.0` or `x.0-alpha.0`. But I only need the major version like `x.x.x` where x are the numbers which  basically indicates the major version.

Comment: That seems like a simple thing to filter for - where's your *code*, what's the *problem* with it?

Comment: I have updated the question with my code. Please have a look

Comment: What do you mean *"doesn't help"*? What's the *output*? Give an actual [mre] - the HTTP request is irrelevant, for example, and versionData doesn't seems to be defined. I'd also suggest using e.g. https://regex101.com/ to ensure your pattern works as expected.

Comment: Thanks. I will try in the given link to make a working regex.

Answer (score 0):

you can use npm programatically (nodejs code), but here is a command line reference for you.

you might use `npm-view` to get what you are after. for instance:

```sh
$ npm view jest --json | jq '."dist-tags"'
{
  "latest": "26.4.0",
  "test": "21.3.0-beta.15",
  "beta": "24.2.0-alpha.0",
  "next": "26.0.1-alpha.0",
  "canary": "25.2.1-alpha.2"
}
```

Comment: The use of `jq` is unnecessary in this instance. Run the following command instead: `npm view jest dist-tags --json`

Comment: It works but still it doesn't solve my problem :( I need a list of all the major versions including current and previous minus beta and experimental versions